# Can't insert russian text into db through mysql script

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create table through mysql script with default values. But when I insert russian text, I have problem with encoding in the result. I've tried to change my.ini file, change CHARSET, add collation... Here is the part of script:

```
   CREATE TABLE `languages` (
      `code` varchar(3) NOT NULL primary key,
      `enabled` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
      `lexem` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
       UNIQUE KEY `code_UNIQUE` (`code`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('RU',1, 'Русский'),('EN', 1,'English');
```

However in Workbench I get smth awful (ðáÐâÐüÐüð║ð©ð╣) in 'lexem' column for code 'RU'. 
Please help.

Comment: I execute `select * from languages` in mysql command shell, and the result is ok.

Comment: Works fine in my MySQL Workbench 8.0.16 against 5.6 MySQL server. Try checking these session variables SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';

Comment: yep, it works. I've change charset to  utf8 in command shell.  Now it's ok. Tnx!